# SharePoint 2010 CSOM get field values of a folder in document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Using client object model, with below caml query able to fetch items with in a folder, but seeing a way to get "folder" field values where these items or documents is residing.

```
+ "<Query>"
            + "   <Where>"
            + "        <Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='int'>0</Value></Eq>"
            + "   </Where>"
            + "</Query>"
```

My code for retrieving folder information...

```
string strFieldValue = string.Empty;
            CamlQuery qryFolder = new CamlQuery();
            qryFolder.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>"
                + "<Query>"
                + "   <Where>"
                + "   <And>"
                + "        <Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='int'>1</Value></Eq>"
                 + "        <Eq><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><Value Type='Text'>"+folderName+"</Value></Eq>"
                + "   </And>"
                + "   </Where>"
                + "</Query>"
                + "<ViewFields>"
                + "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='FieldValue' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' />"
                + "</ViewFields>"
                + "</View>";
            qryFolder.FolderServerRelativeUrl = rootFolder;//+@"/"+folderName;

            ListItemCollection itemColl = docs.GetItems(qryFolder);
            context.Load(itemColl);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            if (itemColl.Count == 1)
            {
                strFieldValue = itemColl[0]["FieldValue"].ToString();
            }

return strFieldValue
```

I get a value here when used caml query with FSObjType is 1 which is for only folders... but unfortunately i get null when query with FSObjType is 0 which queries only files.  My requirement is to get a value even when you are at the file level... Not sure if i'm going correct with the CAML query..

Thanks,
Jameel

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @Thriggle  Basically i'm able to grab a file inside a folder of a document library and the properties (field value) of the file.  Now at the same time i want to retrieve folder properties also in which the file is residing.  However, the folder properties are showing null from the file level.

Comment: Unlike documents, folders don't typically have field values (besides a few like the folder name). What properties are you trying to access? And can you show us the code you're currently using to access the properties?

Comment: Here is my code for retrieving folder information..  I Could able to grab "FieldValue" when queried with <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='int'>1</Value> but not when queried with FSObjType = 0 (for files)..

Answer (score 0):

add to you query this `"<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> "`, just before the `+ "<Query>"`
more details https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/get-items-under-folder-caml